# Length of the shortest binary string that contains as substrings all unique n-length binary strings

Tags: combinatorics

Definition: a binary string is a string comprised exclusively of the characters "0" and "1" (leading 0s are not trimmed).  The length of such a string is the number of characters in the string.

What is the function $f(n)$ that returns the length of the shortest binary string that contains as substrings all unique $n$-length binary strings?

**Examlpes**

| $n$ | $f(n)$ | example string |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 01 |
| 2 | 5 | 01100 |
| 3 | 10 | 0111000101 |

**Work so far**

I know that $f(n)$ will be at most $n*2^n$, which is the number of characters needed to just concatenate all unique n-length binary strings (though for $n > 1$ such a string will definitely have redundancies).

I'm pretty sure that $f(n)$ will be at least $2^n$ due to information theory; if you could make a string containing all possible substrings in less than $2^n$ characters, you could compress binary data beyond the theoretical limit by representing it as an index into such a string.

Comment: If down-voting, please explain why

Comment: Is it [OEIS A052944](https://oeis.org/A052944)?

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts great find.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

$f(n) = 2^n + n - 1$

This is [0OEIS A052944](https://oeis.org/A052944) (thanks to @emacsdrivesmenuts for finding this)

The [de Brujin sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence) for a 2 character alphabet is of length $2^n$.  That contains all substrings if you allow cycling.  In order to not allow cycling, you need to add a repeat the first $n - 1$ characters to the end of the end of the string, hence it will have length $2^n + n - 1$.

You can't add less than $n - 1$ characters to the de Brujin sequence to disallow cycling issue because the de Bruijn sequence has a unique substring of length $n$ starting at each index, including the indices that cycle around.  Thus, the $n$-length substrings that start far enough in the de Bruijn sequence such that they wrap around do not occur anywhere else in the de Bruijn sequence, and need the characters from the front of the sequence that they use to be repeated in order to occur.  For the substring that starts at the last character of the de Brujin sequence, the first $n - 1$ characters of the sequence need to be repeated for it to be present.

Comment: Don't you mean $f(n) \le$, not $=$?

Comment: How do you know that your cycle-fixing approach is optimal? You need to prove there is no other strategy performing better.

Comment: Still upvoted BTW because the answer is useful as it brings up the DB Cycle sequence.

Comment: @WillSherwood:  There are only $2^n$ runs of $n$ characters in a string of length $2^n+n-1$ so this is minimal

Comment: @WillSherwood Good point; I've added a piece to try to address this; let me know if you see a way to tighten up the logic